# Domain of a function involving a radical

Tags: calculus, radicals

$$f(x) = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2} }{x}$$

How do I find the domain of this function? I know that f(x) is not defined when $$x = 0$$ or when $$x = \sqrt{-number}$$

attempt:

$$1 - x^2 \ge 0$$
$$x = \pm 1$$
$$x = 0$$

$$Domain: x\in R : x \neq0, -1 \leq x \leq 1$$

Answer (score 1):

The key is not when $x = \sqrt{-\textrm{something}}$, but rather when $1-x^2 < 0$. If $1-x^2 < 0$, then the radical in the numerator is the square-root of a negative number, and hence it is not real.

Similarly, you identified that $x=0$ causes an issue. So your domain is the reals, minus the points that give you the issues mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the inequality $1-x^2\geq 0$ and combine with $x\neq 0$.

Comment: No, you cannot multiply both sides of the equation by a negative and keep the same inequality. Just think about $(x^2-1)=(x-1)(x+1)\geq 0$. When is $(x-1)(x+1)$ nonnegative? Draw a numberline, it helps. Both your factors have to be positive or negative in order for the product to be nonnegative.

Comment: There are also more problems with your solution than the one I stated above. See if you can figure it out with the hint above.